# When using fprintf I get mirrored array of chars in the output

Tags: c, arrays, char, printf

I'm converting numbers from 10 counting system (c.s.) to another and the printing it to the file.

```
void Fileoutkey(char *res1, char *res2, int sys1, int sys2) //KANON
{
    FILE *fp;
    if(fp = fopen("task_out.cpp", "w"))
    {

        fprintf(fp, "%d: %s\n", sys1, res1);
        fprintf(fp, "%d: %s\n", sys2, res2);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No such file in directory.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

The function of converting (and it is OK)

```
int numSystem1 = 12;
char digits1 [13] = "0123456789AB";
char result1 [18] = "";
int digCount1 = 0;
while (num)
{
    int rem1 = num % numSystem1;
    result1 [digCount1] = digits1[rem1];
    num /= numSystem1;
    digCount1++;    
    for (int i = digCount1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << result1[i]; //here i get 10
    }   
}
```

When converting from 10 to 12 c.s. for, example, number `12` , instead of `10` I get `01`.
Output in the console is right.

Comment: It is the function of printing to the file.

Comment: @ikegami Solving the problem of size is not needed here. But what about NULL? Where should I use it?

Comment: you must share your full code here for better visibility.

Comment: @ikegami so how can I add it to my chars in the code?

Comment: @Elgernon Read the link [mre]

Comment: If we cannot reproduce your problem, it's very hard to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conversion code definitely doesn't work. Taking your example of converting 12 from base 10 to base 12, the loop does the following:

First time around `num` is 12. `12 % 12` is 0 - so that is what is stored as the first character of your string. `num` is then divided by 12 to become 1.

Second time around `1 % 12` is 1 and that is added as the second character. This means your string now contains "01". Which is what you're seeing in your output - your code is adding the digits in reverse order.

You could either work out how big your number is and then count down from that to add the characters in the other direction or reverse the string using.

And also after the loop you need to add the NUL terminator character like this:

```
result1 [digCount1] = '\0';
```

Comment: You're not using `cout` anywhere in the code though.

Comment: It is just because it is not needed for the example. Answer the question.

Comment: @ikegami I tell you that when I just `cout << result1[0]` it brings me `10`.

Comment: That's not a valid program. If `result1` were as you described, that would output just `0`.

Comment: @ikegami Oh yes, you are better C++ machine than mine.

Comment: `cout` doesn't output more than one byte when you pass it a `char`. Either that's not your code, `result1` isn't as you describe, or that's not what the statement outputs. We can't tell you which because you failed to provide a [mcve] again.

Comment: @ikegami check changes.

Comment: You're doing `cout << result1[1];` (which outputs `1`) and `cout << result1[0];` (which outputs `0`). You'd get the same output with `printf('%c', result1[i]);`

Comment: I agree, if you print the number from right to left, it does indeed come out right.

Comment: Putting the `for` loop inside the `while` loop would mean you'd output "010" though

Comment: @ChrisTurner So?

Comment: @ikegami so how should I print it to the file?

Comment: You're already doing that right. What needs fixing is the conversion code, as Chris Turner described.

Comment: You want the loop outside the `while` loop so that it outputs the finished results...

Comment: And it'd also output garbage as `digiCount` is always pointing to the character after the last digit you've added